# The getter 'ws' isn't defined - get_server

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am trying to use `get_server` flutter package for creating a socket server in my flutter application.

According to package documentation, I have tried [this example](https://pub.dev/packages/get_server#like-most-of-the-nodejs-way) but It gives me errors like `The getter 'ws' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'`

```
import 'package:get_server/get_server.dart';

void main() {
  final app = GetServer();
  app.get('/', (ctx) => Text('Get_server of javascript way'));
  app.ws('/socket', (res) {
    res.ws.listen((socket) {
      socket.onMessage((data) {
        print('data: $data');
      });

      socket.onOpen((ws) {
        print('new socket opened');
      });

      socket.onClose((ws) {
        print('socket has been closed');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Error Screenshot
[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  final app = GetServer();
  app.get('/', (ctx) => Text('Get_server of javascript way'));
  app.ws('/socket', (ws) {
    ws.onMessage((data) {
      print('data: $data');
    });

    ws.onOpen((ws) {
      print('new socket opened');
    });

    ws.onClose((ws) {
      print('socket has been closed');
    });
  });
}
```